# Как создать двумерный вектор в куче?

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужен двумерный динамический вектор, который можно будет удалить в любой момент.

Comment: Неважно, где создан сам вектор. В самом объекте `std::vector` хранится три указателя или что-то подобное, а сами данные всегда лежат в куче.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<vector<int>>` вас устроит? Двумерный, динамический, удаляется при выходе из области видимости...

Если нет - сформулируйте вопрос более точно.

Да, я отвечал на вопрос о двумерном массиве, потому что, думаю, что вряд ли вам нужен двумерный именно *вектор* в изначальном геометрическом смысле :), который представляет собой просто пару координат `(x,y)` и вполне реализуется как структура или просто `pair<,>`...

**Update**

Ладно, если вам так хочется "улучшенного С"...

```
int ** a = new int*[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) a[i] = new int[M];

.....

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) delete[] a[i];
delete[] a;
```

Comment: Удалить в любой момент. Наверное используя операцию delete,  а создавать при помощи new

Comment: Да, двумерный массив

Comment: @zhukov Двумерный массив называется матрицей, вектор — одномерный массив.